# How to define the length of a string in an array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

I'm defining an array that will receive many lines of text with between 30 and 40 characters :

```
portfolio_names = np.empty((30000,1)).astype("str")
```

When I run my program, I see that there is a truncation at 32 characters, which causes me an issue. How do I define my array so that it accepts more than 32 characters? Or any workaround as well?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you not just use a Python list instead of a NumPy array?

Comment: `np.empty((30000,1))` produces floats, which when converted to float, allowing for full precision, become 'U32'.  An array of `int` would convert to something else like 'U11' or 'U21'.  Going directly to a defined string length is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array of 40-character unicode strings, you can use the dtype `"40str"` (where `str` is treated [equivalently](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.str_) to the typecode `U`):

```
portfolio_names = np.empty((30000,1), dtype="40str")
```

Comment: I would have used `dtype='U40'`, but the result is the same.